# "Problem does not follow DCP rules" when I use "ceil" and"sign" function , how to avoid this?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

I am trying to solve a job assign problem , The goal is to assign the same job to the same person as much as possible, within the constraints of satisfying the ability limits

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
c=np.array([[0,1,1],
            [0,1,1],
            [0,1,1],
            [1,1,0],
            [1,1,0],
            [1,1,0],
            [1,0,0],
            [1,0,0],
            [1,0,0]
            ])
d=np.array([[1,1,1],
            [1,1,1],
            [1,1,1],
            [2,2,2],
            [2,2,2],
            [2,2,2],
            [3,3,3],
            [3,3,3],
            [3,3,3]
            ])
x = cp.Variable((9,3),integer=True)
#obj = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(cp.multiply(c,x)))
x1= cp.multiply(d,x)
x1= cp.vstack((n,x1))
e = cp.diff(x1,k=1, axis=0)
f = cp.abs(e)
g = cp.sign(f)
obj=cp.Minimize(cp.sum(g))
con= [0 <= x, x <= 1,cp.sum(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)==1,
      cp.sum(cp.sum(cp.multiply(c,x),axis=0))==9]
prob = cp.Problem(obj, con)
prob.solve(solver='CBC')
print("Best value is :",prob.value)
print("Best solution：\n",x.value)
```

Below is the trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/N000377/Documents/python/Recipe Grouping help update .py", line 33, in <module>
    prob.solve(solver='CBC')
  File "C:\Users\N000377\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 459, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\N000377\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 939, in _solve
    solver, gp, enforce_dpp, verbose)
  File "C:\Users\N000377\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 566, in get_problem_data
    solver=solver, gp=gp, enforce_dpp=enforce_dpp)
  File "C:\Users\N000377\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 792, in _construct_chain
    enforce_dpp=enforce_dpp)
  File "C:\Users\N000377\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cvxpy\reductions\solvers\solving_chain.py", line 155, in construct_solving_chain
    reductions = _reductions_for_problem_class(problem, candidates, gp)
  File "C:\Users\N000377\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cvxpy\reductions\solvers\solving_chain.py", line 92, in _reductions_for_problem_class
    "Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:\n" + append)
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
sign(abs([[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3.]] @ var0[1:9, 0:3] + -[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3.]] @ var0[0:8, 0:3]))
```

The same thing happens if I want to use ceil function, my thought is to count the job type , or can we just create a count function ?

Comment: This looks like homework to me. You need to do your own homework or you won't learn what you need to know to do the job you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is (almost) never a good idea to use a ceil() or sign() function. They are non-differentiable and not continuous (and certainly non-linear).

You can simulate a ceiling function in a MIP model as follows:

```
y=ceil(x)
```

is approximately equivalent to

```
 y >= x
 y <= x+0.999
 y integer
```

I typically use 1 instead of 0.999 and let the solver pick the best if x is already exactly integer-valued.